# DXA 2.0 GetNavigationModel url Property for Keyword is null

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, dxa-net, web8-cu1

I am working with a client that has DXA 2.0 (.NET) and SDL Web 8.1.

- DXA Unity.config is configured to use the DynamicNavigationProvider
- The Sitemap [Navigation] Category has been published
- Pages have been associated with the keywords from the Category using the sitemapKeyword metadata field
- The Pages have been Published

When I make a request to the following URL, in the json returned, none of the Keywords have an URL Property associated with them.

http://localhost:55517/api/navigation/subtree?descendantLevels=3

If I use the content service to retrieve the Pages associated with one of the Navigation Keywords all of the expected Pages are returned.

I have set all of the caching in the Microservices to a very short timeframe and have verified that this is not a caching issue.

How/where does the DXA Framework/Microservices get the URL Property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL Property being null in this case is due to the following configuration in the Deployer Microservice `cd_storage_conf.xml`

```
<Taxonomies CountEnabled="false"/>
```

This configures the taxonomy reference count for keywords, if `CountEnabled` is set to False the reference count for keywords will not get updated. The default setting is that the keyword counts are enabled.  In the out of the box `cd_storage_conf.xml` this entry is commented out.

DXA 2.0 `DynamicNavigation` with Category and Keywords is dependent upon the Broker database containing the reference counts for the Keywords. After changing the Deployer's config and republishing the Category I was able to see the URL's for the Keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Structure Groups, Categories and Keywords don't have a URL of themselves. In order to simulate a Navigation Model built from Structure Groups, the following algorithm is used:

- If the Taxonomy Node (Keyword) has classified Pages and one of those
  Pages is an Index Page (i.e. has a URL ending with `/index`), the
  Taxonomy Node gets the URL of the Structure Group containing that
  Index Page. For example:

  - A Taxonomy Node which has a classified Page
    with URL `/autotest-parent/regression/taxonomy/index`  will get the
    URL: `/autotest-parent/regression/taxonomy`
  - A Taxonomy Node which has a classified Page with URL `/index`  (the Site Home Page) will get the URL: `/`
  - A Taxonomy Node which does not have a classified Index Page
    does not get a URL (`null`)`
- The Taxonomy Root Node (Category) cannot have classified Pages itself and will therefore not have a URL.
- If a Taxonomy Node does not have a URL, its `Visible` property will be set
  to `false`, resulting in the item not showing up in Top Navigation and
  Context Navigation (it should show up in Breadcrumb and Sitemap,
  though).
- If classified Pages are not included in the subtree (on-demand Navigation scenario), we don't have enough information to determine the Taxonomy Node URL and it will therefore not be set (`null`).

Comment: So in my case, the pages I have associated the keywords with have the filename being index but, the TaxonomyNode is not showing the URL property.